After SDK package update, Android no longer building locally in terminal
I keep getting this Android Build Error output after updating one of the SDK's my react-native project requires. Now, android emulator / simulator no longer builds directly from terminal due to build errors related to ':app:mergeExtDexDebug' and 'dexing'.
What is happening??? Any help is appreciated to understanding what's going on!
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform transact-3.5.0.aar (financial.atomic:transact:3.5.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=26, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /Users/random.name/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/55f06f208d760e88994e43fb4a15cdff/transformed/jetified-transact-3.5.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform muppet-0.0.0-alpha5.aar (financial.atomic:muppet:0.0.0-alpha5) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=26, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /Users/random.name/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/728437359a5ccea59ec1c153fbb992f5/transformed/jetified-muppet-0.0.0-alpha5-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm-1.6.2.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm:1.6.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=26, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /Users/random.name/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/204c4327a726ff2b08e0a597cd1cfaf2/transformed/jetified-kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm-1.6.2.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   ......

android/build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }

    ext {
        versionName = "100.00.0"
        minSdkVersion = 26
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 33
    }
}

android/app/build.gradle
android {
    defaultConfig {
        compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "someId"
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion          
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
    }

